# customize visual studio intelliSense while in design mode (webforms aspx)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

in many cases intelliSense is coming to help when setting values to attributes or properties.

so as soon as you hit `=` (or `:` within style attributes) it will suggest all options available to be set.
(according to the parameter you choose to assign with a value)

for example : `font-family` in style,  as soon as you type `:` , you get to be offered by all fonts available .

my question is **how could i make a custom suggestion ?**

it looks like it's in `C#`, an `enum` type.

**in my case** <sub>(if it's relevant to the answer...)</sub>

I would like to add to intelliSense, a list of parameters values of my own, so as soon i will hit `=`
it will offer me the options to set (those I previously added to visual studio).

this is an example for what i was looking to implement,

in the `Ajax AutoCompleteExtender`  could be one more parameter to set if you choose to . `ContextKey`

```html
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolKitScrptMan1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
        TargetControlID="TBX_FontsAC" runat="server"
        MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true"  
        ServiceMethod="FontNamesList_AutoCompDataSrc"
        FirstRowSelected="true".... and some more parameters......>
 </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

as it's only one of the options to go about , that is what i would like for now , as I remember there was some other scenarios i was thinking about it , so I've decided to try and implement this idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can edit the Intellisense files `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas`, there's some info on it here:

http://blog.whconsult.com/2008/11/20/AddingIntellisenseToVisualStudioForCustomConfigurationSections.aspx

Be careful though! Back everything up first!

Comment: thanks! , did you add anything like  your own custom values to any parameter ?, the example there is not so much of a help ...